# Why cant I break blocks in minecraft? I can place blocks but i cant break them. Im ready to smash my computer!

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I cant break blocks and im starting to get angry bc i spent $30.00 on this game for my computer!

Comment: are you left clicking to break?

Comment: You've not provided much info to work with.  Is this Mac/PC?  Are you on a server?

Comment: Also, in survival, you press left and *hold* until the block is broken. (depending on blocks, tools and status effects it may be instant or it may take minutes... dirt and wood are quite fast, 2-3 seconds with bare hand). Spamming left-click doesn't do a thing, the timer to break the block is reset every time you release the button.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a mouse, click left click. If you have a trackpad, click with one finger on the trackpad. Hope this helps!